# Minizinc - convert txt or csv to dzn

Tags: input, minizinc

How can I convert a txt file or a csv file into a MiniZinc datafile (dzn)?

I need to work with several excel files which include single value parameters, matrices and lists of names. The aim is to build a sequencing for a small plastic factory.

Thanks for advice

Comment: Your question gives no clue as well. What's the format of the `txt` / `csv` file? Any example? Where's the `mzn` file?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no tool in the MiniZinc distribution that do this, so you have to write your own program for this conversion. 

The format of the .dzn file is the same as for the data in a MiniZinc file which is described (at least with examples) in the  Tutorial.